# Pulling large quantities of data takes too long. Need a way to speed it up

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm creating a client dashboard website that displays many different graphs and charts of different views of data in our database.

The data is of records of medical patients and companies that they work for for insurance purposes. The data is displayed as aggregate charts but there is a filter feature on the page that the user can use to filter individual patient records. The fields that they can filter by are

- Date range of the medical claim
- Relationship to the insurance holder
- Sex
- Employer groups (user selects a number of different groups they work with, and can turn them on and off in the filter)
- User Lists (the user of the site can create arbitrary lists of patients and save their IDs and edit them later). Either none, one, or multiple lists can be selected. There is also an any/all selector if multiple are chosen.
- A set of filters that the user can define (with preset defaults) from other, more internally structured pieces of data. The user can customize up to three of them and can select any one, or none of them, and they return a list of patient IDs that is stored in memory until they're changed.

The problem is that loading the data can take a long time, some pages taking from 30 seconds to a minute to load (the page is loaded first and the data is then download as JSON via an ajax function while a loading spinner is displayed). Some of the stored procedures we use are very complex, requiring multiple levels of nested queries.  I've tried using the Query Analyzer to simplify them, but we've made all the recommended changes and it still takes a long time. Our database people have looked and don't see any other way to make the queries simpler while still getting the data that we need.

The way it's set up now, only changes to the date range and the employer groups cause the database to be hit again. The database never filters on any of the other fields. Any other changes to the filter selection are made on the front end. I tried changing the way it worked and sending all the fields to the back end for the database to filter on, and it ended up taking even longer, not to mention having to wait on every change instead of just a couple.

We're using MS SQL 2014 (SP1). My question is, what are our options for speeding things up? Even if it means completely changing the way our data is stored?

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide any specifics - so this is pretty generic.

**Speed up your queries** - this is the best, easiest, least error-prone option. Modern hardware can cope with *huge* datasets and still provide sub-second responses. Post your queries, DDL, sample data and EXPLAINs to Stack Overflow - it's very likely you can get significant improvements.

**Buy better hardware** - if you really can't speed up the queries, figure out what the bottleneck is, and buy better hardware. It's so cheap these days that maxing out on SSDs, RAM and CPU will probably cost less than the time it takes to figure out how to deal with the less optimal routes below.

**Caching** - rather than going back to the database for everything, use a cache. Figure out how "up to date" your dashboards need to be, and how unique the data is, and cache query results if at all possible. Many development frameworks have first-class support for caching. The problem with caching is that it makes debugging hard - if a user reports a bug, are they looking at cached data? If so, is that cache stale - is it a bug in the data, or in the caching?

**Pre-compute** if caching is not feasible, you can pre-compute data. For instance, when you create a new patient record, you could update the reports for "patient by sex", "patient by date", "patience by insurance co" etc. This creates a lot of work - and even more opportunity for bugs.

**De-normalize** - this is the nuclear option. Denormalization typically improves reporting speed at the expense of write speed, and at the expense of introducing lots of opportunities for bugs.

Comment: if you go after the buy beter hardware option keep in mind you are going to follow your own tail there..  the faster the data grows the more and more often you have to invest to keep up.. meaning in the longer run you might be investing more then when you tryed optimizing it first.